# Mongoose: Property 'watch' does not exist on type 'Model<guildInterface>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I want to listen to all changes made in my documents with watch model event.

```
interface guildInterfaceextends Document {
    guildid: string,
    guildname: string
}

let guild = mongoose.model<guildInterface>('guilds', GuildSchema);

guild.watch("change", console.log);
```

`guild.watch()` is returning a type error `Property 'watch' does not exist on type 'Model<guildInterface>'`

**Mongoose Version:** mongoose@6.3.1

Comment: did you miss the paranthesis? `mongoose.Model<guildInterface>(schema)`

Comment: I forgot to add schema in question but it is present in my code and i have updated the question here too.